# Is there a reliable way to dodge Snorlax's Hyper Beam?

Tags: pokemon-go

My local gym sometimes has an 1800cp Snorlax with Hyper Beam. I've got Pokémon with upwards of 140 HP but, if I get hit by Hyper Beam even once, I always go from 90% health to annihilation.

I can see when the Hyper Beam is about to start. What *specifically* can I do to increase my chance of dodging it? I can swipe right so fast that the graphics swing to 90 degrees to the right of Snorlax, but there is still about a 1/3 chance of instant death.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some research on the interwebs, I've found some helpful hints for you and your Snorlax predicament.

From [a rant on a post from the GameFAQs Forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/180967-pokemon-go/74133725?jumpto=6):

> Just dodging isn't enough, and the positioning isn't relevant. You can be standing behind your opponent and he can still hit you. The mechanic is based off timing. What matters is when you dodge. The timings are different for each attack. The important ones to learn are the charge moves, and even then you only really need to master the popular ones: hyper beam, solar beam, hydro pump, heat blast, blizzard, stone edge, etc. The ones that will 1HKO you.

and:

> Machamp or other fighting types at high CP make short work of him.

I've read in quite a few forums that dodging Hyper Beam is all in the timing. As soon as you see the screen flash yellow, you want to swipe to the side to dodge. To get the hang of it, I sometimes will go to gyms I know I can't beat and use my low-level Pidgeys and other Pokemon that I don't really care about (that I will likely transfer or evolve just for XP afterwards), just to practice and get better at it. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aflKgUWuIvQ) a quick video that shows perfect dodging (no HP lost whatsoever).

The key is practice. I know you probably didn't want to hear this, but the key really just is practice. Don't sweat too much, Snorlax's Hyper Beam can be dodged when timed correctly. [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_M5pZFTKIiuFLb2RZuCQ1fwJd_7aQkx_j-oMrYUVPME/preview#heading=h.ag44jw77oiqq) is an unofficial guide to Pokemon Go; I found the 'Dodging' subsection under the 'Gyms' section particularly helpful and interesting when I was learning and mastering dodging. Stick with it, and you'll be avoiding all those Hyper Beams in no time.

**EDIT:** Also, if you find that you are swiping at the same exact time for every Hyper Beam, and some you dodge perfectly and some you get hit, it may also be a server issue. There is always the probability that you didn't time the dodge correctly, but often these *high fidelity-requiring* moves malfunction when you have a bad internet connection.

Comment: That video is pretty good.

Comment: very nice answer

Comment: Good idea with the pidgey practice

Comment: That is a great idea about sacrificing pidgeys. But, do you know if pokemons have different levels of dexterity?

Comment: @khaeson I don't have a source for this, but in the other games the quicker Pokemon were usually electric or fighting types (Pokemon with the move _Quick Attack_ and similar)

Comment: @ThePickleTickler I think I've notice the electric quickness. My gambit is to pour stardust into my 3 Jolteons and use them as shock troops to smash the unfairly high HP water Pokemon. This work, but... not against a Snorlax. If I don't learn how to exploit the quickness advantage, Snorlax will keep chewing-up my Jolteons.

Answer (score 0):

Many people incorrectly try to look at how the defending pokemon moves in order to time their dodges. For some moves, the dodge window does not match the pokemon animation very well (most notably, blizzard).

In order to dodge properly, you should mainly look at the spark animations around the pokemon. These sparks indicate the dodge window. A good way to practice paying more attention to these sparks is to do this:

- Turn on AR mode and enter the gym fight
- Turn your phone away from the defending pokemon so that you cannot see it at all
- For a start, without attacking, try dodging correctly each time a spark animation appears
- When you master that, start attacking between the sparks, still trying to dodge each spark accurately
- After some practice, go back to "normal" mode (AR turned off) and do the same thing, and remember to not look at the movement of the defending pokemon, only at the spark animations